# using Fill function in adapters in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dataset

im new to asp.net.
i want to use my dataset an adapter in order to display all the data in 1 of my tables.
i read about using fill(table) but i cant use the table like in the example.

my db table is Cars,
my dataset page is DataSet1.xsd,
my adapter name is CarsTableAdapter.

would like to get explaination about that cause i didnt get it from other webs.
im using visual web developer 2010 in cs files, not vb.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapterda fill method is overloaded method you can pass here datatable as well as dataset.

Try below code:

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapterda=new SqlDataAdapter();
da.Fill(ds);
```

You can access dataset as shown below:

```
   DataTable dt= ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: i tired that code:
http://jsfiddle.net/3zJcL/
and its not displaying anthing..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.CarsTableAdapter cta2 = new DataSet1TableAdapters.CarsTableAdapter();
DataSet1.CarsDataTable cdt = new DataSet1.CarsDataTable();
cta2.Fill(cdt);
```

that is working for me, thanks anyway.